# Matching crystal planes on a wafer with the reference frame of electrical permitivity tensor?

Tags: symmetry, crystals, photonics

If I understand correctly, if I were to work on an InP (100) wafer substrate, that would mean that the circular plane facing me would be the (100) plane of the crystal lattice. Now, I'm interested in studying electro-optical effects of InP. Let us take the Pockels effect for example. Let $\eta=\epsilon^{-1}/\epsilon_0$. Expanding it we usually end up with:

$$
\Delta \eta = \sum_k r_{ijk}E_k
$$

and usually $r_{ijk}$ is greatly simplified based on symmetry arguments to just a few non zero elements. My question now is: How do I match the reference frame used on this tensor with the crystal planes?

Comment: For many wafers there is a flat or other indication of how to orient within the plane of the wafer so one could determine the (010) and (001) directions.